# Chrome doesn't update the url line on refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browser-history

I am working on a RoR based web-application.
OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Our tester posted interesting bug.I doubt it bothers end users, anyway i am curious why it occurs and how to workaround it.

We have an "href=" link leading to the homepage.
Steps to reproduse:

1. I am on the homepage
2. Move focus on url row and type "blahblah"
3. Push that href

Result in Chrome(Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)):

- Page is reloaded
- URL stay "blahblah"

Result in Firefox(40.0.3):

- Page is reloaded
- URL changed to correct one, to which the href leads

I looked for JS workaroundfound the following variants:

1. window.location.assign("needed_url");
2. var state = {
   "canBeAnything": true
   };
   history.pushState(state, "Home Page", "needed_url");

Again both works for Firefox but neither of them for Chrome.
The needed_url is root, for Dev environment it is http://localhost:3000

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Probably that Chrome is deciding it is a search term (because that bar is not just for URL's) and Chrome is doing you a favour by remembering what you was about to search, so you don't have to type it again. I can't see that there is anything to try and work around. It's what Chrome does, just leave it at that

Comment: Actually, testing it on my Chrome 45 it actually resets the URL back to stackoverflow. So can't even replicate your scenario. I also don't see how `href` is involved here. You seem to just be talking about typing in the search bar

Comment: @musefan you must be right regarding that chrome consider blahblah as search request. However it is strange behavour keeping the request in URL line, when clicking on link, don't you think?